# On the proof of if $a_n \rightarrow l$ then $\ln(a_n) \rightarrow \ln l$.

Tags: real-analysis

I have seen a proof that if $a_n \rightarrow l$ then $e^{a_n} \rightarrow e^l$

The way I was shown this is by constructing a sequence $b_n \in Q$ s.t.

$$a_n - 1/n < b_n < a_n + 1/n $$

This sequences converges to $l$ by the sandwich theorem and can be constructed thanks to the fact that the reals are dense.
Also we have $|a_n -b_n| = |b_n - a_n| < 1/n$ so $b_n - 1/n < a_n < b_n +1/n$ and this means that

$$\frac{e^{b_n}}{e^{1/n}} = e^{b_n - 1/n} < e^{a_n} < e^{b_n +1/n} = e^{b_n} e^{1/n}$$

And because I know that the limit of the product is the product of the limits and that the definition of exponential of a real number is the limit of a sequence of exponentials of rationals that converge to said real number I obtain

$$e^l < e^{a_n} < e^l$$

And then our proposition follows from the sandwich theorem.

Now I wanted to prove on my own that if $a_n \rightarrow l$ then $\ln(a_n) \rightarrow \ln l$ in a similar way but I get a bit stuck when having to use the definition of logarithm anyone mind lending a hand?

Comment: Just as a comment, "thanks to the fact that the reals are dense" does not mean much. Also, all this has more to do with continuity than anything else :), i don't understand this proof for $e$ as it goes to $\mathbb{Q}$ to end by defining exponential using its "continuity" .

Comment: @Stravog I mean that because $a_n - 1/n < a_n + 1/n $ and these are both real numbers we can always find a rational in-between them $\forall{n}$, would I need additional justification for this? Also I just want to limit myself to not use continuity as an exercise but I get your point.

Comment: No no it was only about the formulation, real are not dense, still rationals are dense in reals. Still, I don't really get which are the premises, in the first proof you provide. What is known and unknown ?

Comment: @Stravog ah ok thanks a bunch! And the premises basically are using only sequences theorems and results (no continuity) is it possible to prove that $\ln(a_n) \rightarrow ln(l)$ given that we have proven that $e^{an} \rightarrow e^{l}$ and the definition of exponent is the one given in the question.

Comment: is $l$ positive?

Comment: yeah but what is the exponential of a rational and why $e^{a+b}=e^{a}e^{b}$ stands for them ?

Comment: @pelto If you have a proof for $l$ positive that is nice!

Comment: @Stravog The exponential of a rational $b \in Q$ is $e^b = e^{p/q} $ and we understand this because it is just just powers and roots of integers, the property you state is now an easy proof for exponential or rationals. The exponential function has the usual definition. But yes in my premises you can't use $e^{a+b}=e^{a}e^{b}$ where $a$ and $b$ belong to the reals.